# Man kennt „zu handhaben“. Ist „handhaben” trotzdem trennbar?

Tags: infinitive, separable-verb

Man kennt den Ausdruck:

> leicht zu handhaben

<strike>In Wörterbüchern lautet es auch, dass *handgehabt* das Partizip von *handhaben* ist</strike>  Irgendwo hatte ich *handgehabt* gesehen, wo genau, weiß ich nicht mehr.  Dementsprechend könnte man eher *leicht handzuhaben* für genannte Form erwarten.

Wenn die Schlussfolgerung, dass die Trennbarkeit eines Verbs aus dessen `Präfix+ge+[Partizipform des Verbes, das durch das Weglassen des Präfixes entsteht]`-Partizipform (in diesem Fall *handgehabt*) abgeleitet werden kann, nicht falsch ist: Wie koexistieren die beiden Begriffe in diesem Verb? Spekulierend, liegt das Problem an dem unüblichen „Präfix“ *hand*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laut meiner Recherchen gibt es kein *handgehabt*. [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/handhaben:V:haben) gibt es als *gehandhabt* an und der Duden nennt dieses Beispiel:

> die Vorschriften werden hier sehr lax gehandhabt

Im Allgemeinen würde ich auch bei einem Verb wie *handhaben* zu einer Flexion tendieren, die das Wort als ein Ganzes auffasst. Das Präfix *hand-* ist nicht sonderlich produktiv und wohl recht alt, daher wird es vermutlich auch nicht zur Satzklammer verwendet. Solche Worte werden mit der Zeit zu festen Verbindungen ohne Bezug zu ihren einzelnen Bestandteilen so wie beisp. *Lichtung* (Kein Mensch erkennt hier mehr *licht(en)* und *-ung* im Vergleich zu beisp. *Überlegung*, dessen *-ung*-Form ohne Weiteres jederzeit von *überlegen* gebildet werden könnte).

*handhaben* ist da ähnlich wie *staubsaugen* oder *downloaden*. Im Eifer des Gefechts kommen schon mal Bildungen wie *staubgesaugt* zustande, aber prinzipiell ist es standardsprachlich *gestaubsaugt*.

Comment: Sorry, ich muss mich verguckt haben. Ich sollte eigentlich die Frage löschen. Die Sache ist, dass diese Antwort doch die Frage beantwortet.

Comment: @c.p. Die Frage ist nicht ganz so verkehrt. Man findet eine Reihe an Übersetzungen bei Linguee, wo fälschlicherweise "handgehabt" geschrieben wurde. Allgemein scheint es ein gängiger Fehler zu sein. https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/handzuhaben.shtml. Es gibt auch in einigen anderen Foren Themen dazu.